# Services are not listed in Karaf while migrating from Felix SCR to OSGI Declarative Services

Tags: maven, osgi, osgi-bundle, apache-felix, declarative-services

I'm Migrating from Felix SCR Annotations to R6 OSGI Declarative Services but the Service is not listed inside karaf .As per below code **SampleServiceImpl**  should list is karaf .But it is not listing .
Is there any other configuration i have to in pom.xml ?

```
package com.sample.test;


import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Activate;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.ReferencePolicy;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.ConfigurationPolicy;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Deactivate;

    @Component (configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.OPTIONAL, immediate = true, service = SampleService.class)
    public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService
    {
    
     @Reference (policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC, service = AgentService.class , bind = "bindAgentService",unbind ="unbindAgentService")
    private AgentService agentService;
    
     
     @Activate
        protected void activate() {
            System.out.println("activate ");
        }
    
        @Deactivate
        protected void deactivate() {
            System.out.println("de-activate ");
        }
    }
```

This is the pom.xml I am using .

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <groupId>com.test.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>compile</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>

  
  <dependencies>      
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
       <artifactId>osgi.cmpn</artifactId>
       <version>6.0.0</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>   
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
@Reference (policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC, service = AgentService.class , bind = "bindAgentService",unbind ="unbindAgentService")
```

You list 2 methods, `bindAgentService` and `unbindAgentService`, which do not appear in your class. You also apply the `@Reference` annotation to a field. What do you want? Field injection? Method injection? Both? If you only want field injection, remove the `bind` and `unbind` elements in the annotation.